# boxplot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

I don't understand why some point are not taken by boxplot

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{frenchmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{variations}
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed}}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=latex ,terminaloptions=rotate,scale=.75 ]

        set key off
        set style increment default
        set style boxplot
        
        set style fill solid 0.25 border lt 2
        set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7
        set style data boxplot
        set boxwidth  0.5
        set pointsize 0.5
        set border 2
        set xtics ("A" 1, "B" 2) scale 0.0
        set ytics nomirror
        set yrange [0:20]
        plot 'boite2.txt' using (1):1
        \end{gnuplot} 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

the data (in `boite2.txt`) are :

```
12  
9
9
10.5
3
12
11 
18
9
12.5
9.5
5
```

to see the result :

[image: two points wrong ?]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, are you wondering why the whiskers doesn't cover the full data range from 3 to 18?

Comment: To expand on the comment of @TorbjørnT.: could you explain which points from the file are not taken?

Comment: i must find how to put an image here...

Comment: When you write/edit a post, there is a button above the text field for adding images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNLwW.png, keyboard shortcut is Ctrl + G. (Doesn't work in comments.)

Comment: thx :) so  i will edit the post.

Comment: Right, that's the same output I got, but you still haven't said what output you expect to get. The two dots mark the outliers (3 and 18), the whiskers cover a range as described in the Gnuplot manual: "By default the whiskers extend from each end of the box for a range equal to 1.5 times the interquartile range (i.e. the vertical height of the box proper). Each whisker is truncated back toward the median so that it terminates at a y value belonging to some point in the data set." If you want the whiskers to extend to 3 and 18 you need `set style boxplot fraction 1`, but what do you want?

Comment: Yes ! that's work :) thx a lot.

Comment: must i (could ?) close the subject ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments and it's also actually somewhat off-topic because it is about gnuplot and not about LaTeX.